# Why is a decimal place being removed when I insert data? SQLite (Android Development)

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am attempting to enter values such as "0.20" within a table but when I display it within an activity it shows "0.2". I am uncertain as to why the '0' is being removed i.e. incorrect structure of the table, insertion, or being returned.

My table is created as followed:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_NAME
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_SWIMMERLAPS + " INT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_SPONSOR + " DEC(4,2) NOT NULL );");
```

I then insert the data:

```
public long addSwimmer(String name, String laps, String sponsor) {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(laps);
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    cv.put(KEY_SWIMMERLAPS, i);
    cv.put(KEY_SPONSOR, (new DecimalFormat("0.00##")).format(0.20));
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}
```

and then return the sponsorship data:

```
public String getSwimmerSponsors() {
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_SPONSOR };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,
            null, KEY_SWIMMERLAPS + " DESC");
    String result = "";

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        result = result + c.getString(0) + "\n";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Edit - I display the returned result in my layout as follows:

```
String sponsors = swimmerDb.getSwimmerSponsors();
    tvSponsor.setText(sponsors);
```

Thanks.

Comment: becouse that's the way how sqlite works ... use `String.format(...)` + `Cursor.getDouble(...)`

Comment: Could you expand on this? Although, I'm sure you are correct - I'm relatively new to Java and I'm not so sure what you mean.. Could you perhaps provide a more detailed example. Thanks.

Comment: `for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        result = String.format("%s%.2f\n", result, c.getDouble(0));
    }` now it's clear ? edit: forgot f in format string!!

Comment: Thank you. If you provide an answer I will be able to accept it.

Comment: Dᴀᴠᴇ Nᴇᴡᴛᴏɴ add his answer few seconds after my comment ... it's almost the same as mine ....Larry Lustig's answer is good too (remeber about floating point implementation disadvantages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're displaying an unformatted Java variable, and leading/trailing 0s are suppressed.

If you want to format it with a specific layout, use one of the `printf`/`format` variants:

```
printf("%.2f", num); // Etc.
```

Comment: [Downvote explanation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes)

Comment: @Sheldon No worries, just confused :) I just like knowing in case I totally missed something, which happens far more than I care to admit.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I expect that the reason for the downvote is that the actual answer to this question involves the SQLite data affinity and storage class systems.  The user believes that he is storing data into a DECIMAL field but he's not, he's getting an SQLite NUMERIC field.  The reason your answer works because it's converting the value to TEXT, it's the textification that makes SQLite store the trailing 0.

Comment: @LarryLustig But the display happens on the Android side; a NUMERIC-affined (?) column value may or may not keep a trailing 0 after conversion, no? It seems like in order to do this reliably you'd need to always format on the Java side, but I may be (wildly) misinterpreting how/when sqlite3 converts, and to what.

Comment: I see.  I took it that you were suggesting modifying the routine `addSwimmer` to format the value to string before inserting into the database.  Rereading, I see you're advising him to format it for display only.  That works fine, although I think it's important for the user to understand that  root of his problem is that the `DEC(4,2)` data type doesn't exist in SQLite.

Comment: @LarryLustig Ah, gotcha. Agreed.

Answer (score 1):

When talking numbers 0.20 and 0.2 are exactly the same. If you want to keep the formatting than I suggest you insert the value as a formatted string.

```
cv.put(KEY_SPONSOR,0.20);
```

turns into

```
cv.put(KEY_SPONSOR, (new DecimalFormat("0.00##")).format(0.20));
```

**EDIT:** If you go this way, don't forget to change the KEY_SPONSOR column type from DEC to TEXT

Comment: I changed to code and I appear to be getting the same result. However as @Dave suggested - it may be the way I am formatting it in my layout. I've edited my question to reflect the changes that I made and how I'm displaying the returned value within my layout.

Comment: I don't think it is the layout that does that as you are inserting the value as string into the DB so the return should be the exact same string...

Comment: You forgot to change the KEY_SPONSOR type to string in the insertion query : "...KEY_SPONSOR + " DEC(4,2) NOT NULL"

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not offer DECIMAL or any similar type where you can specify the precision.  The only data type with decimal places is REAL and that is how your number is being handled.

If you need specified precision you can multiply (by 100, in this case) and store as INTEGER, or use a TEXT column.